# Yún not detecting SD card

Tags: arduino-yun, sd-card

My Arduino Yún is not detecting my previously working SD card. The metal contacts *are* closed. There is *no* dmesg output after plugging in the SD. It does not detect a different SD.

Any ideas for what's wrong?

[image: SD card plugged into Arduino Yún]

Comment: I wrote about the contacts because other people have had that issue, and my yun is upgraded

Comment: Looking at the image, that SD card is not completely inserted into the Yún.